# Highcharts xAxis shows labels from drilldown on drillup

Tags: scrollbar, highcharts, drilldown

When I click on district it shows villages on drilldown but when i drillup it shows xAxis data  along with labels from drilldown i.e. village name with District name. 
I wish to display only the district names on drillup and only the villages name on drilldown.
Also can I hide the xAxis series showing as 1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5  if there is no more district name.
Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/prachi_chandra/3e4Lnctm/3/

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me fix this. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(function() {

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        lang: {
            drillUpText: '? Back to Main'
        }
    });


    // Create the chart
    var defaultTitle = "Population District Wise";
    var drilldownTitle = "Population Village Wise - District: ";

    // Create the chart
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {

            height: 320,
            type: 'column',
            renderTo: 'chart_div1',
            events: {
                drilldown: function(e) {
                    chart.setTitle({
                        text: drilldownTitle + e.point.name
                    });
                },
                drillup: function(e) {
                    chart.setTitle({
                        text: defaultTitle
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: defaultTitle,
            align: 'center',
            y: 5,
            style: {
                fontSize: '12px',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true
        },

        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true,
            barBackgroundColor: 'gray',
            barBorderRadius: 7,
            barBorderWidth: 0,
            buttonBackgroundColor: 'gray',
            buttonBorderWidth: 0,
            buttonArrowColor: 'yellow',
            buttonBorderRadius: 7,
            rifleColor: 'yellow',
            trackBackgroundColor: 'white',
            trackBorderWidth: 1,
            trackBorderColor: 'silver',
            trackBorderRadius: 7
        },

        xAxis: {

            min: 0,
            max: 5,
            type: 'category'
        },

        yAxis: [{ //--- Primary yAxis
            title: {
                text: 'Population'
            }
        }],



        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        plotOptions: {

            series: {
                name: 'Population',
                maxPointWidth: 30,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Population',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'District',
                y: 28,
                drilldown: '20'
            }]
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: [{
                id: '20',
                data: [
                    ['Village1', 6],
                    ['Village2', 22]
                ]
            }]
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div1" style="margin:0px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is probably to remove `max: 5`. Then you won't see the wrong category label and you will also not see the slots that are empty. See [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3e4Lnctm/4/) demonstration.

Comment: Did I mention that I have to use scrollbar too as I have to show only a few village names at a time from the total of 120 village names  for the clearer data view if i dont set max value then it will show all the villages name in single view which is inconvenient to read.

Comment: @Prachi, you could update the `min` and `max` as you are drilling up and down. See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/3e4Lnctm/5/).

Comment: Thank you so much ! I set the min and max on event as per your suggestion and it's working.